# neomodel: how to share index across StructuredNode Objects

Tags: python, indexing, neo4j, cypher, neomodel

how is it possible in neomodel to share a unique index across node objects, without instantiating separate objects to just hold the indexed data?
I'd like to find the object based on a index query, e.g like this:

```
...
mynode = BaseObject.index.get(uid=uid_of_Type1Object)
# mynode is now of type `Type1Object`
```

with

```
class BaseObject(StructuredNode):
    uid = StringProperty(unique_index=True)
    ...

class Type1Object(BaseObject):
    ...
    def assign_uid(self, guid):
        # I may need tweaking of uid generator
        # on subclass level
        self.uid = guid

class Type2Object(BaseObject):
    ...
    def assign_uid(self, guid):
        self.uid = guid
```

Comment: "neomodel" doesn't exist as a tag... maybe if one of the bigmen is kind enough to help out.. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In https://github.com/robinedwards/neomodel/commit/1f1b43377b25cd4d41e17ce2b7f9ca1a1643edea it was added support for custom index on StructuredNode subclasess

```
class BaseObject(StructuredNode):
    __index__ = 'MyBaseIndex'
    uid = StringProperty(unique_index=True)
    ...

class Type1Object(BaseObject):
    __index__ = 'MyBaseIndex'
    ...
    def assign_uid(self, guid):
        # I may need tweaking of uid generator
        # on subclass level
        self.uid = guid

class Type2Object(BaseObject):
    __index__ = 'MyBaseIndex'
    ...
    def assign_uid(self, guid):
        self.uid = guid
```